# Uploading Postgresql repo to CentOS

Tags: centos, permissions, postgresql

I've been wrestling with getting my repo set up on Vultr CentOS server, and ran into several issues. In short, I want to know how people get their backend repo up on the CentOS server. Is moving the local repo folder into `/root/` on the server correct?

The most recent issue is this:

Running `npm run migrate`, results in

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/Repofolder/backend'
(node:14581) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined.
```

now this error

```
> backend@1.0.0 migrate /root/Repofolder/backend
> postgrator --config postgrator-config.js

[14:24:20] table schemaversion does not exist - creating it.
[14:24:20] version of database is: 0
[14:24:20] migrating up to 2
Error: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I've set up migration with postgrator, `postgrator --config postgrator-config.js`.

After running into issues with users and permissions while logging into psql and creating database, and editing `pg_hba.conf` several times, I'm not so sure if this is how others would approach getting their repos up on CentOS (how would I push my local changes with this setup?) I've also ran into issues with using Docker and setting up `db_url`,

```
DB_URL: process.env.DB_URL || 'postgresql://postgres@localhost/dbname'
```

I actually need to push up my frontend code as well, which I am thinking of getting it up on the same server, with different ports:

`80` for frontend, `8000` for express, and `5432` for postgres.

I'm not able to find resources on how people set up their Postgres full stack projects on CentOS.

Comment: do you run this as root or regular user? why the assumption of moving it to /root? you can place it anywhere where your user has access rights.

Comment: @Bart I run as root, `[root@vultr ~]#`. I don't have specific reason as to why into /root. I just assumed that that's where it would go.